# Setting text on ProgressDialog crashes app

Tags: android

I'm learning android and I don't know why this code doesn't work. Can you tell me why it doesn't work and take me correct code?

```
    final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(LoginScreen.this, "", "Loading. Please wait...", true);
    Thread loggingStatus = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try
            {
                sleep(2000);
                dialog.setMessage("Logging in. Please wait.");
                sleep(2000);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    loggingStatus.start();
```

Comment: Explain in detail "doesn't work". Error? Exception? Wrong output? Also explain specifically what part you don't understand.

Comment: and post the logcat details

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should not set the Text of ProgressDialog in background thread . All UI updation should be done only on UI thread(Main thread)

Either use `AsyncTask` or `Handler` for this logic or functionality

Answer (score 0):

You have to move the portion of the background task that updates the ui onto the main thread. There is a simple piece of code for this:

> `putting runOnUiThread( new Runnable(){ .. inside run():`

```
  final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading. Please wait...", true);
        Thread loggingStatus = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            sleep(2000);
                            dialog.setMessage("Logging in. Please wait.");
                            sleep(2000);
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                });

            }
        };
        loggingStatus.start();
```